# TypeScript: Can I assert a value to a type with different property names?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-conversion

I am working with an API and a web framework.

I have an interface `IResponse`. It looks something like this

```
interface IResponse {
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
}
```

When I get an API response, I get an array and assert the value as `IResponse[]`

However, the Web Framework I'm using requires me to convert this `IResponse[]` to an `IComboBoxOption[]` which has the following interface:

```
interface IComboBoxOption {
    key: string;
    text: string;
}
```

Right now, I am converting it like this:

```
const convertedResults: IComboBoxOption[] = [];
const results = await APICall(productsRequest) as IResponse[];

results.forEach(r => {
    convertedResults.push({
        key: r.Id,
        text: r.Name,
    });
}
```

However, there are a large amount of results and the forEach loop takes too long. Ideally, I would like to skip the conversion step all together, and directly assert the API return value as an `IComboBoxOption[]`.

Is this at all possible?

**Note: I have no control over the property names returned by the API, and I must use this Web Framework.**

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to just *claim* that the type is correct without actually converting it?  That's what "assert" means.  I mean, nothing stops you from doing that, but I doubt you'll be happy.  I can assert that I'm lighter than air but it won't stop me from falling if I step off a cliff.  What are you envisioning here, exactly?

Comment: @jcalz Is there a way I can say to interpret the "Id" property as the "key" property on the IComboBoxOption. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the names of the properties without iterating over each value. But you can use a method that has more performance:

Using ES6 array methods tend to work faster
https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/

try using this:

```
const convertedResults: IComboBoxOptions = results.map((r) => ({
  key: r.Id,
  text: r.Name,
}));
```